# In Vivado, how to instantiate a user defined "Block Diagram" inside of the top-level "Block Diagram"?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I've imported my VHDL code into a user defined Block Design, and I exported my I/O interfaces from this block design, now I need to instantiate this Block Design in the top level Block Design that contains the Xilinx Zynq Arm core and AXI interconnect.  When I right click on the Top-level Block Diagram, I see two choices:

"Add Module"
"Add IP"

neither of these two options lists the Block Design that I created to instantiate my VHDL code.  Any ideas on how to get this to work?

If you create a user defined Block Design, how can you instantiate it inside of another Block Design, specifically the top-level Block Design.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but i just read this:  When you have created an IP integrator BD, implemented it, validated it, and tested it on the
target hardware, and you are satisfied with the functionality of the BD, you can package the BD
to create an IP that can be reused in another design.
For more information on packaging a BD for use in the Vivado IP catalog, see this link in the
Vivado Design Suite User Guide: Creating and Packaging Custom IP (UG1118).

Answer (score 1):

You can only use 'add module' if the top level is Verilog or VHDL.
(Of course you still have to add the source code files to the project using the big '+') button)

The top level module should **not** be System-Verilog or VHDL2008. It will not show up in the list. You can uncheck the 'hide incompatible module' box after which it shows the incompatible modules but you still can't add them.

You *can* turn System-Verilog or VHDL2008 in to IP using the Xilinx IP flow and then you can add them.
But I find it rather cumbersome and I also do not see the use of making IP to replace it again and again with a 'new' version until it has been verified.

So adapt the top-level or write a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/59355.html, it seems to now be in tools/create or package new ip/next/package a block design from the current project/...